# Dynamically merge all objects in different arrays (appending names instead of ignoring)

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, concatenation

I want to combine two arrays with common properties:

```
var ranking = [{
    def: "0.58",
    league: "Scottish Premiership",
    name: "Celtic",
    off: "3.33",
    grank: "3",
    tform: "96.33",
},
{
    def: "2.52",
    league: "Scottish Premiership",
    name: "Dundee",
    off: "1.28",
    grank: "302",
    tform: "27.51",
}]
var matches = [{
date: "2010-04-22",
league: "Scottish Premiership",
home: "0.0676",
away: "0.8",
draw: "0.1324",
goals1: "3",
goals2: "1",
tform1: "96.33",
tform2: "27.51",
team1: "Celtic",
team2: "Dundee",}]
```

Expected output looks like this:

```
[{
date: "2010-04-22",
league: "Scottish Premiership",
home: "0.0676",
away: "0.8",
draw: "0.1324",
goals1: "3",
goals2: "1",
tform1: "96.33",
tform2: "27.51",
def1: "0.58",
def2: "2.52",
off1: "3.33",
off2: "1.28",
grank1: "3",
grank2: "302",
team1: "Celtic",
team2: "Dundee",}]
```

To merge the arrays, I used [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge) _.merge function

```
var result = _.merge(ranking, matches);
```

The output it returned did merge some objects and omitted homogeneous objects.

Please I need some insight in achieving this task.

Comment: You want as result an array with 1 object inside. This consists of all properties from matches and all properties from both array-elements from ranking where the property-name becomes a1 or 2 at the end?

Comment: That's correct. Objects that are common to both teams in ranking, should be should be renamed with "...1" and "...2"

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to extract unique props and call it on each list of objects you wish.

```js
var ranking = [{
    def: "0.58",
    league: "Scottish Premiership",
    name: "Celtic",
    off: "3.33",
    grank: "3",
    tform: "96.33",
  },
  {
    def: "2.52",
    league: "Scottish Premiership",
    name: "Dundee",
    off: "1.28",
    grank: "302",
    tform: "27.51",
  }
]
var matches = [{
  date: "2010-04-22",
  league: "Scottish Premiership",
  home: "0.0676",
  away: "0.8",
  draw: "0.1324",
  goals1: "3",
  goals2: "1",
  tform1: "96.33",
  tform2: "27.51",
  team1: "Celtic",
  team2: "Dundee",
}]

function extractUniqueProps(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
      keys = Object.keys(x);
      keyValue = keys.map((y, j) => ({
        [y + i]: x[y]
      })).reduce((acc2, y) => ({
        ...acc2,
        ...y
      }), {})
      acc = {
        ...acc,
        ...keyValue
      }
      return acc;

    }, {}

  )
}

const result = { ...extractUniqueProps(ranking),
  ...extractUniqueProps(matches)
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Good effort, but the code can't handle multiple arrays. Instead, the appended "0" and "1" went incremental for each object. eg: "name0"..."name2509"